# Where is the character in physics option of blender 2.7?

Tags: game-engine, interface, physics

Following these two tutorials, I can't figure out where is the character option in blender 2.7:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jxaHT_AFt_w

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=187knmhldR4

Comment: you should accept iKslR's answer as correct

Answer (score 5):

First, make sure the current render engine is set to *Blender Game*. If you then switch to the *Physics* tab you will find the option under *Physics Type*.

[image]